# Implementing Azure Key Vault using a corporate proxy

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

The recommended way of implementing Azure Key Vault in .NET Core is with this example

```
// using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();

                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                    builtConfig["AzureADApplicationId"],
                    builtConfig["AzureADPassword"]);
            }
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Is there a way to customize this set up code for this call to Azure using a web proxy? I've found documentation for what to do with Key Vault behind a corporate firewall and what IPs need to be listed, but looking to see if there is a way to be able to use the proxy as well with some kind of HttpHandler in the HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this, it does not look like there is currently a way to handle this through a proxy. You have to instead add the IPs to your Firewall. This article explains it further:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-access-behind-firewall#ip-address-ranges

Answer (score 1):

`AzureKeyVault` client use `HttpClient.DefaultProxy` for create connection. You can specify proxy in environment variables like `HTTPS_PROXY`, see [HttpClient.DefaultProxy Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=netcore-3.1)